# Re-installing Fedora 20: are automatic partitions safe to use?

Tags: partition, system-installation

I intend to re-install Fedora 20 on a new computer as I am having a lot of trouble with the installation done by the vendor of the computer. It is a dual boot machine with a small Windows XP3 partition for things I cannot do in Linux (mainly proprietary software for electronic devices)

It may be my fault fumbling things that has caused the problems, but anyway I want to re-install it from the official DVD. My question is: can I just accept the automatic partitioning, will it preserve the existing partitions, and will the dual boot Grub still work?

I have no data stored on the new machine: all that was backed up on separate hard drives from the old one, and I have done no permanent work on the new one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of frustration I decide to try a well-established version of Fedora instead of the newly released 20 installed by my computer supplier. I have now installed version 17, and, so far, all the problems seem to have been solved. I can now use yum with no trouble. I also was apparently missing a lot of the software, like gnuplot and ghostscript. I suspect that the installer of Fedora 20 had not included the software developer's repositories.

In this installation process I had the option to replace the existing Linux, and that took care of the partitioning doubts.

So, now my question is answered, and I have, fingers crossed, upgraded from Fedora 12 to a decent working Fedora again.

Comment: the "issue with yum" that you're referring to may have been caused by Fedora's decision to replace `yum` with the next-generation package management system `dnf`. You can read more about `dnf` and fedora20 by searching online; feel free to read [this article](http://dnf.baseurl.org/2013/12/19/dnf-and-fedora-20/) as well on the project's "blog site?".